# How can I check if an item has already been marked as an asset?

Tags: asset-browser

I'm creating a an asset library using the Asset Browser features introduced in version 3.0.

How can I know for sure that an asset has already been marked without having to open the library in the Asset Browser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using the interface

In the outliner, objects that have been marked as assets have an icon with books on the left of their name :

[image]

Materials and Worlds have an additional display hint in the material and world properties :

[image]

[image]

Depending on the data type you may or may not be able to mark an asset twice using the interface, but if you can you will be greeted with an error message :

[image]

### Using Python Scripting

If an object has been marked as asset, one can access its [library asset data](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID.asset_data) using `ID.asset_data`.It has the nice added benefit of returning `None` if the item is not an asset.

So one can define a function to determine if an [ID](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html#id-bpy-struct) is an asset:

```
def is_asset(obj):
    return obj.asset_data is not None
```

Testing on a brand new file :

```
import bpy


def is_asset(obj):
    return obj.asset_data is not None 

obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
obj.asset_mark()
print(f"Is {obj.name} an asset ? {is_asset(obj)}")
obj.asset_clear()
print(f"Is {obj.name} an asset ? {is_asset(obj)}")
```

Prints in the console :

```
Is Cube an asset ? True
Is Cube an asset ? False
```